# thumbnail slider size is not applied correctly codex:add_image_size wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, size, thumbnails

Have a problem i upload one image with 400px 300px 
functions.php and I have defined the following

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );//Agrega soporte
   add_image_size( 'slider-thumbnail', 940, 310, true ); // Slider thumbnail
}
```

header.php

```
<?php query_posts('' ); 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider-thumbnail');  ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"></a>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But when he grabs the picture appears to scale and repeated not being adjusted to the size you set it, I want to engage me esque size 940px to 310px but defined to deform me why this happens?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to crop a picture to a bigger size than it is. Do you have a larger resolution version you can upload?

Comment: do not quite understand what you mean, mean bigger load another image?

Comment: Are you trying to resize a 400px x 300px into a 940px x 340px image?

Comment: yes, if, although deformed, but the problem is that enlarges, but the image is repeated

Comment: Can you try change the cropping style by removing the ", true" and see if that works?

Comment: did you regenerate the thumbnails?

Comment: yes i used plugin for it, but its same, slider-thumbails apply repeat image ill try add array with one class and into css add width and height and dont work